# Threads with async Task functions C#/.NET / await not compiling

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

I have a project where I need multiple data for a list of projects. For each project I call an api to get me this information. The loop works, although it takes 4 to 5 minutes to finish(Which is A LOT).

The code used to look like this :

```
foreach (var project in projects)
{
    string url = urlOneProject + project.name + secondPartUrl + "?authtoken=" + authToken;
    HttpWebRequest request;
    request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    request.Accept = "application/json";
    request.ContentType = "application/json";
    var executions = new Execs();

    var response = (HttpWebResponse)(await request.GetResponseAsync());

    using (response)
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            var objText = reader.ReadToEnd();
            executions = (Execs)js.Deserialize(objText, typeof(Execs));
        }
    }


    execs.AddRange(executions.executions);
}
```

To improve performance I thought that using threads might be a good idea. So, I came up with something like this:

```
ManualResetEvent resetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
int toProcess = projects.Count;
foreach (var project in projects)
{
    new Thread(() =>
    {

        string url = urlOneProject + project.name + secondPartUrl + "?authtoken=" + authToken;
        HttpWebRequest request;
        request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Accept = "application/json";
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        var executions = new Execs();

        var response = (HttpWebResponse)(await request.GetResponseAsync());

        using (response)
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                var objText = reader.ReadToEnd();
                executions = (Execs)js.Deserialize(objText, typeof(Execs));
            }
        }

        lock (execs)
        {
            execs.AddRange(executions.executions);
        }

        if (Interlocked.Decrement(ref toProcess) == 0)
            resetEvent.Set();
    }).Start();

}
```

The problem with this code is that the line:

```
var response = (HttpWebResponse)(await request.GetResponseAsync());
```

doesn't compile anymore from the moment I added `Thread`. And the error I get is

> "The 'await' operator can only be used within an async lambda expression "

That wasn't a problem when I didn't use threads. The `GetResponseAsync` is an `async` function and the use of the `await` is compulsory. I tried deleting it (which wasn't logical I agree but I ran out of options) but the compiler tells me I need an `await` for an `async` function.
I don't quite understand what changes with the implementation of the `Thread`.

Didn't I use the threads mechanically correctly? What should I do to correct this or to implement what I want to do correctly?

Comment: To fix compiler error you need to pass async lambda to thread constructor: `new Thread(async () => ...`

Comment: You would get more milage out of async / await and Task.WhenAll than launching Threads explicitly. (and give preference to Tasks rather than Threads - less likely to shoot yourself in the foot).

Comment: If you want to split those `Task` per `project` using `Task` instead of `Thread`, just use `projects.Select(async project => ...`

Comment: Threads are way too expensive and you don't want too many threads/sockets at any one time either.

Comment: While @StuartLC provides an excellent answer. If you're going to continue down the `async` path it would be worthwhile to look into the [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/sp-http/httpclient) that has a great deal of straight forward `async` support.

Comment: Noted, definetly going to check that. The answer @StuartLC provided helped a lot, still need to understand everything he did before jumping to something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing multiple paradigms of coding, viz `async / await`, and oldschool Thread starting and synchronization, which is likely to lead to trouble.

As per the above comments

- The reason your code doesn't compile is because you are attempting to use `await` in otherwise synchronous code passed to the thread. You can qualify lambdas as `async` as well.
- `Task` is a much safer paradigm than `Thread`, and [TPL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-parallel-library-tpl) provides rich and expressive tools to assist in asynchrony and parallelism.
- If you process each parallel task in isolation, without sharing any data (such as the collections that you are locking), but instead return the resultant data from each Task you can then use LINQ to collate the results in a thread-safe manner.

```
var myTasks = projects.Select(async project =>
{
    var url = $"urlOneProject{project.name}{secondPartUrl}?authtoken={authToken}";
    var request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(url);
    request.Accept = "application/json";
    request.ContentType = "application/json";

    using (var response = (HttpWebResponse) (await request.GetResponseAsync()))
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        var objText = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Execs>(objText);
    }
});

var execs = (await Task.WhenAll(myTasks))
    .SelectMany(result => result.executions);
```

**Other notes**

- Don't use `JavaScriptSerializer` - even the [MSDN docco](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) says to use NewtonSoft Json
- There's an async version of `reader.ReadToEndAsync` which I've included.
- You can drop the locks and the `ManualResetEvent` - since each Task returns it's result, we'll leave it to `Task.WhenAll` to collate the data.
- You can flatten the children of multiple `executions` with a `SelectMany`
- Adjacent `using` clauses are stackable - it saves a bit of eyestrain on the indentation.